Why is Google OAuth JS code raising an error?
I'm struggling to find the issue. I'm getting this error:
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}

I'm running this function:
async function connectToYouTube() {
   console.log('connect to youtube, clientId: ' + user_store.get_clientId);
   try {
      googleSdkLoaded(google => {
      google.accounts.oauth2
         .initCodeClient({
         client_id: user_store.get_clientId,
         scope: 'email profile openid',
         redirect_uri: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_REDIRECT_URL,
         callback: response => {
            if (response.code)
               fetchUserDataFrom(response.code)
               console.log('connect to youtube, clientId: ' + user_store.get_userData);
         },
         })
         .requestCode()

   })
        // Fetch YouTube subscribed channels
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error signing in with Google', error);
   }
}

this is the fetchUserDataFrom() function:
const fetchUserDataFrom = async (code) => {
      try {
        localStorage.setItem('gCode', JSON.stringify(code))

        console.log('Google connect, redirect_uri: ' + import.meta.env.VITE_APP_REDIRECT_URL, 'code: ' + code, 'clientId: ' + clientId.value, 'clientSecret: ' + clientSecret.value);
  
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
          {
            code,
            client_id: clientId.value,
            client_secret: clientSecret.value,
            redirect_uri: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_REDIRECT_URL,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          },
        )
  
        if (data) {
          const accessToken = data.access_token
  
          // Fetch user details using the access token
          const userObj = await this.axios.get(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
              },
            },
          )
  
          if (userObj && userObj.data) {
            // save copy in storage
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userObj.data))
            userData.value = userObj.data
          }
          else {
            // Handle the case where userResponse or userResponse.data is undefined
            console.error('Failed to fetch user data')
          }
        }
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to exchaange token', e)
      }
    }

I've double-checked the redirect uri to be http://localhost:8080/google_auth/for both the OAuth and Web-client in the google console. And the .env reference in the code, but still the same error.
Anyone have any clues or ideas to bring me forward?
Thank you,
Rune

axios.post sends a JSON request by default, but I don't think Google's token endpoint accepts that? Add 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to your request headers.

I know it's a stupid question but always good to check. Can you make sure there isn't an extra '/' at the end of your endpoints on both the console and your .env?

Thanks guys. Will check. I'm sure that there is a trailing '/' both places, but it should be without trailing '/'?

For the future feeders. The redirect_uriwhen calling the oauth2.googleapis.com/tokem should be set to simply just post message, then it worked for me. Not sure why ;)
          'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
          {
            code,
            client_id: clientId.value,
            client_secret: clientSecret.value,
            redirect_uri: "postmessage",
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          },
        )

BR,
Rune
